# how to fix this error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

I am using PHP 7.2.18. I want to establish a database connection with MS Access.

```
  <?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
$conn = odbc_connect('access_dbname','','');
if ($conn) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
?>
```

When I run it, I get the error as undefined function odbc_connect().
I have tried repeatedly enabling odbc extension in php.ini file but didn't work. Also I am using wamp server.

Comment: Did you kill and restart your wamp server? Changes to php.ini generally don't take effect until the webserver is restarted. Beyond that, try bringing up a `phpinfo()` page and see if it is available/enabled there.

Comment: Yes I tried restarting the server after making changes to php.ini but still I found no odbc driver in phpinfo().

Answer (score -1):

Since WAMP is a Windows installation, you will need to grab the php_odbc.dll file from somewhere and throw it into your PHP install directory. Then you can change the ini file and restart the server.

You can download it from here:
https://www.pconlife.com/viewfileinfo/php-odbc-dll/

Comment: php_odbc.dll file is already there in the PHP install directory but its not working.

Comment: did you stop the server, change the ini then start it again? or did you change the ini while the server was running?

Comment: I got the solution by uninstalling the wamp server and installing the xampp. I edited the php.ini file and enabled odbc extension there. Then I restarted the apache server and it worked. Thanks a lot.